# Email sending not working using Apache James

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, james

I am trying to send email using apache james but the emails are not getting delievered. Below is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        String user = "test";  

        String password = "test"; 
        String fromAddress = "test@localhost";   
        String toAddress = "test@gmail.com";        
        Properties properties = new Properties();     
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");     
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");     
        properties.put("mail.smtp.username", user);     
        properties.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
        properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp"); 

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);      

        try             
        {         
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);         
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));         
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toAddress));          
            message.setSubject("Email from our JAMEs");         
            message.setText("hiiiiii!!");         
            Transport.send(message);          
            System.out.println("Email sent");     
        }     
        catch (MessagingException e)     
        {        
            e.printStackTrace();     
        } 
        }
}
```

Also test user is added in apache james having password test. Requesting you to kindly help me out in the same.

Comment: Do you actually have a mail relay running on the `localhost`?

Comment: Well, if you don't already know then the answer is probably no. But you can test by telneting to localhost, port 25. If there is one running you will be able to connect and it should print the name of the mail server. Make sure to have local echo turned on in your command shell.

Comment: Also, you could try putting the try/catch clause around the entire main method to check if any exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: hello everybody...i did telnet localhost 25 and it gave me message that apache james smtp server is running.....also i put try in the entire method than also it is not showing any exceptions....

Comment: i went to inbox folder and in that it was written Error message:
553 #5.1.8 Domain of sender address <test@localhost> does not exist....but when i give command listusers i am able to see test....kindly help me out....

Answer (score 1):

I think problem caused by this:

Email servers before accepting any mail do a reverse dns query. They check the ip for domain that the email came from and the ip that email is really came from.

If ip of domain and ip of email sender does not match, mail servers think that email is junk or spam.

Here since your domain (localhost) is not a valid address when Email server send a reverse dns query does not get an IP and think your mail is junk or spam.

For more information check this: http://wiki.junkemailfilter.com/index.php/Fixing_Reverse_DNS

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.  What I did:

1. Go to the path : \apps\james\conf
2. Open for edit the filename 'james-fetchmail.xml'
3. Change "fetchmail" from false to true as:
4. Restart the Apache James Server.
5. You would see the following messages printed on the console after you start the server:

James Mail Server 2.3.2
Remote Manager Service started plain:4555
POP3 Service started plain:110
SMTP Service started plain:25
NNTP Service started plain:119
FetchMail Started

*Now, run your program.  It should work!*

Comment: I did changes fetchmail from false to true...but still getting error 553 #5.1.8 Domain of sender address <test@localhost> does not exist.....

Comment: According to [this](https://james.apache.org/server/3/feature-protocols.html): FetchMail,[...] is a component that allows the administrator to configure Apache James to retrieve email from a number of POP3 servers and deliver them to the local spool. This is useful for consolidating mail delivered to a number of accounts on different machines to a single account. More information on configuring FetchMail can be found [here](https://james.apache.org/server/3/config-fetchmail.html). It doesn't look related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added the domain "localhost"?
If not, add the domain first, and after create the users.

$ james-cli AddDomain -h 127.0.0.1 localhost

## check if domain exists

$ james-cli ListDomains -h 127.0.0.1

And, how do you started james? Using james.bat?